# How to make PDF preview directly without having to download it

Tags: java, html

I have to upload a PDF file on my website. But I want my users to have a preview of it when shared over sms, email, etc without having to download it as browsers usually do. Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Serve it from a direct URL with the appropriate `Content-type` header and no `Content-disposition`

Comment: @Phil Can you show me some example, I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

If the `content-type` header is set correctly it should trigger the browser to display the pdf.

Depending on your application you may also wish to use a javascript viewer like [ViewerJS](https://viewerjs.org/) for example however this may be overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your html page. Only support chrome and mozilla browser.

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf" width="100%" height="147px">
       <p>Your browser does not support PDFs.
       <a href="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf">Download the PDF</a>.</p>
    </object>
```